# svg text to path conversion without inkscape, illustrator

Tags: css, svg, font

A variety of tools facilitate conversion of text strings to SVG curves for a given font and style parameters, [opentype.js](https://opentype.js.org/) being among them.

I am trying to discover a way to convert an SVG file with text into one without, the text being converted into scalable paths, such that the resulting SVG file displays the same as the input file, on any compliant SVG viewer, without dependency on the fonts being locally available.  Headless invocation of the conversion operation, for scripting, is essential.

Currently, I am only aware of two tools that generate an SVG file with text converted to paths, namely Inkscape and Illustrator.  I have no license for Illustrator.  Inkscape has an open license, and conveniently offers a command-line interface for text-to-path conversion, but Inkscape regrettably has its own view of what an SVG file ought to look like.  Output from Inkscape generally looks little like the input, unless that input was also created by Inkscape.  Class tags are dropped and replaced with extensive, verbose inline style details, for each element.

Features that are useful in a solution include:

1. Output appears indistinct from input.
2. Output has no text elements.
3. Generated path elements in output have same style and class information as text elements used to generate them.
4. Non-text elements are copied from input to output with little or no change.
5. Output style details do not include text style, no longer needed for correct display.
6. Operation can be invoked from command-line.
7. Font definitions can be passed from command line, in case they are not available on system.

I realize that it is unlikely that any currently-available tools offer all of these features.

Would anyone suggest a place to look for one that helps move toward the desired direction?

Comment: I think you can tweak the Inkscape output quite a bit, by saving it as "Optimized SVG". Then a  dialog will show up that specifies if+how attributes are converted, with many other options. Inkscape will remember these settings. However I cannot say anything about  the font conversion issues.